# Sending data from Controller to View in Laravel 7

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, web

I want to send my data from controller to  xedit.blade.php, but I get the same error:

```
 Undefined variable: users
```

in controller:

```
public function index3()
    {
        $users=User::all();

    return view('xedit')->with('users' => $users);

    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/index3','Admin\UsersController@index3');
```

and I want to use $users in blade.Maybe there is a Route problem?

Comment: You're using arrow notation `=>` without using an array. The correct way to declare the return statement would be `return view('xedit')->with(['users' => $users]);`. Alternatively you could use `compact` as seen in one of the answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code logic is perfect, I guess you have to use proper naming with your routes because of Laravel Standard.

```
Route::get('/admin/show','Admin\UsersController@index')-name('admin.show');

public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('xedit')->with('users' => $users);
}
```

In view, blade use a professional approach like below

```
@isset($users)
 ... loop ...
@endisset()
```

check record before sending to view by using dump and die function dd($users);

Answer (score 2):

in your index method

```
public funtion index()
{
     $users=User::all();
     return view('xedit', compact('users'));
}
```

in your view add $users

```
<table>
    @foreach ($users as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to comment but doesn't have 50 reputation

Replace `('users' => $users);` this with `(['users' => $users]);` as you are using `=>`